# Angular2 ng-template within HTML form tag

Tags: angular, bootstrap-modal, forms, angular2-ngmodel, ng-template

I am iterating through an array and generate a drop-down per element. For some reasons when I click the Add button other drop-down values become un-selected (blank)! I have put a debugger on the Add method and I can see that the previously selected values are still there. Not sure why their drop-downs become un-selected (blank) though!

I created a sample [Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ndkjel?file=app%2Fapp.component.html)! 
Once remove the form tag everything works fine. but why??

Comment: an example over https://stackblitz.com/ to replicate what you are trying would help us solve it asap

Comment: here is an example [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ndkjel?file=app%2Fapp.component.html)